# RSA code giving result after more than 10 minutes

Tags: rsa

I am trying to implement RSA algorithm. I got a code in python. When I run it, it takes more than 10
minutes even when the primes are within 100 and message size is 8 decimal digits. Plese suggest  what may be the problem in the code.

```
# Write Python3 code here 
from decimal import Decimal


def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)


p = int(input('Enter the value of p = '))
q = int(input('Enter the value of q = '))
no = int(input('Enter the value of text = '))
n = p * q
t = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

for e in range(2, t):
    if gcd(e, t) == 1:
        break

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = 1 + i * t
    if x % e == 0:
        d = int(x / e)
        break
print('pvt key= ', d)

ctt = Decimal(0)
ctt = pow(no, e)
ct = ctt % n

dtt = Decimal(0)
dtt = pow(ct, d)
dt = dtt % n

print('n = ' + str(n) + ' e = ' + str(e) + ' t = ' + str(t) + ' d = ' + str(d) + ' cipher text = ' + str(
    ct) + ' decrypted text = ' + str(dt))
```

Comment: What primes within 100 are selected? And what are the decimal digits of size 8.
It seems impossible that it takes more than 10 minutes.

Comment: If p,q are less than 100 then n is less than 9999, and RSA does not work for messages >= n (or < 0). Also note the primes must be _distinct_ or RSA doesn't work; see the basic definitions in wikipedia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What we've got here is a so-called naive implementation, which doesn't consider time complexity of power-then-modulo operations involving large integers. I'd recommend you to read up on square and multiply, exponentiation by squaring, binary exponentiation, for a bit of context. Typical naive implementations have O(2<sup>m</sup>) complexity, while optimised versions could achieve only O(m).

If you replace the commented-out code with the uncommented, you'll get significant execution speed improvements:

```
# ctt = pow(no, e)
# ct = ctt % n
ct = pow(no, e, n)
...
# dtt = pow(ct, d)
# dt = dtt % n
dt = pow(ct, d, n)
```

See Python built-in function [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) for more details of what I've done.

Please note I did not verify reminder of your algorithm.

Comment: The question's code already does multiplication by squaring (or similar), because two-argument `pow` does. What remains to be gained (which is, a lot) comes mostly from early modular reduction. Wikipedia has an [article on modular exponentitaition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). If one is _really_ into making things as fast as they can be, there's R. Brent and P. Zimmermann's [modern computer artihmetic](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/pub226.html).

Comment: Your answer showed me path to go ahead. I felt that  really efficient operation can reduce execution time drastically. Thank you very much for giving attention here.